# How to calculate a surface area of a river?

Tags: surfaces, surface-integrals

I am doing a math exploration and I was wondering if someone could help with this problem. What will I need to use in order to calculate SA of a river? What parts of math are used? What info will I need about that river? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to know the width of the river at each point along its length.

Comment: Is this question somewhat related to physics?

Comment: What will I use in terms of math? Integrals?

Comment: Nope, purely math is what I need

Comment: do you have an accurate map of the river? You could approximate the SA by placing thin rectangles of known area on the map and then adding those rectangles.